# Is there a way to add an image as a keyframe in 2d animation?

Tags: animation, grease-pencil, 2d

I created a drawing in Medibang and I'm wondering if I can put it as a keyframe into my animatic?

I want to put it in the "Strokes" object so that all of my keyframes are in one place. From what I can understand, I can insert an image as a plane, background or reference. I read that background and reference won't appear in the final render, and I'm kinda lost on how the "plane" setting works.

What I'm hoping to achieve is to make the image appear for around 50 frames with a little bit of camera motion going from up to down. Then after the image, I plan on animating the rest of my animatic using Blender's tools.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Create a rectangle stroke with the same proprtions as the image, create a new material, in edit mode select the rectangle and click the assign button on material tab.

Set the material as "Fill", select the "texture" style, choose the image and set loc, rot and scale.

[image]